# Redirecting into a pipe

Tags: redirect, pipe, gawk

Is there a way to filter stdout (or stderr) before being redirected to a file?
"redirecting to a pipe" is probably not the best way to put it but I'm looking for the easiest way to achieve something with that effect.

The usage scenario is the following. I'm using gawk --lint-invalid by principle to detect possible errors in my scripts and want to filter out spurious ones. Instead of redirecting errors to a file and grepping them out when examining the file, I would like the filtering to take place before writing to the file.

Example: this script prints every second line to stderr.

```
echo -ne 'a\nb\nc\nd\n' | gawk --lint=invalid 'BEGIN {b = 1;} // {if (b) print; else print > "/dev/stderr"; b = !b;}' 1>/dev/null 2>errors
cat errors | less

gawk: warning: regexp constant `//' looks like a C++ comment, but is not
b
d
gawk: (FILENAME=- FNR=4) warning: no explicit close of file `/dev/stderr' provided
```

But you can see the spurious gawk warnings (they are not of concern). They could be filtered for example, using

```
filter-gawk-output.sh
---------------------
grep -Ev 'looks like a|explicit close'
```

Is there an elegant way of doing that in-line when redirecting to errors file?
Right now when examining error files I always do

```
cat errors | ./filter-gawk-output.sh | less
```

Comment: Here comes the inevitable comment about your (granted, admirably consistent) Useless Uses of Cat. See http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: @tripleee: I could argue that my use of cat makes the pipeline input more obvious, and doesn't require an additional parameter to my scripts; on a more practical note, when you try a lot of things, starting the pipeline with a `cat` makes it easier to add a grep or a sed etc. inbetween

Comment: I suspect there are no ways for `gawk` to redirect the diagnostic to other places than stderr. If this is the case, then the question is really about general syntax for your shell of choice (`bash`, `tcsh`, `zsh` or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
gawk --lint=invalid 'whatever' INPUTFILE 2> GAWK_ERRORS.LOG
```

This way `STDERR` will be redirected to the error log.

Comment: Ok that's the way it works now, what I want is to NOT output those spurious gawk errors like the ones mentioned in my post, to GAWK_ERRORS.LOG. Bear in mind that my GAWK_ERRORS.LOG will not contains only **gawk** errors but also a lot of diagnostics that I myself am inserting in the script code (that calls other scripts etc.). Having a complex script it would be nice to get only relevant error messages. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of `gawk` having facility to change the output of warnings. So I think this is more a question about shell syntax.

Given

```
filter_warnings() { grep -v '^gawk:'; }
awkprog='BEGIN {b = 1;} // {if (b) print; else print > "/dev/stderr"; b = !b;}'
```

where `filter_warnings` is for filtering out the `gawk` warnings and assuming `bash` as your shell, we can direct `stderr` to pipe command using `|&` syntax:

```
echo -ne 'a\nb\nc\nd\n' | gawk --lint=invalid "$awkprog" |& filter_warnings
```

If you want to outputs to file, then need to use parenthesis:

```
(echo -ne 'a\nb\nc\nd\n' | gawk --lint=invalid "$awkprog" > output.1) |& filter_warnings > output.2
```

Here `output.1` will contain the `gawk` program output to `stdout`  and output.2 the program output to to `stderr`.

Comment: Hi and thanks, this seems on the right track. But, imagine that my gawk invocation (your last line in your answer) is inside a script, and the script is not doing the file redirection, the outside world is. So if I use the |&, the error is mixed with the output, and both are filtered and outputted.

Comment: What I need is to leave the standard output untouched, and just filter the standard error, everything inside a script. Then this script would have the correct standard output, and the filtered standard error, available for redirection into whatever files the caller wants. Does it make sense?